# XmlSerializer serializes but doesn't deserialize

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm using the XmlSerializer class from System.Xml.Serialization
My datatypes are marked with the appropriate attributes
e.g.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XMLFile")]
public class OrderXml
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "SalesOrders")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "SalesOrder")]
    public List<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }

    public OrderXml()
    {

    }
}
```

When serializing, there are no problems.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(save_to_path + $"Orders_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")}.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    xs.Serialize(fs, new OrderXml() { SalesOrders = order_resp.results });
}
```

However, when attempting to read the files that this program has written,
there are no exceptions but all of the fields have default values:

```
OrderXml ox = null;
using(Stream s = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
{
    ox = (OrderXml)xs.Deserialize(s);
}
```

What have I missed that allows serialize to work, but prevents deserialize from working properly?

Comment: I've just tried using System.Xml.XmlReader -- Same results. So I'm guessing there's a problem with the dataset itself. Something to do with missing attributes maybe?

Comment: Could you provide your XML string, which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Is there a minimal repro here? This looks like it should work, as long as the xml that you're trying to deserialize is from serializing the same model, but runnable code we can play with that shows the problem would really help

Comment: @MaikHasler pretty sure JSON won't work well :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
And it has nothing to do with XmlSerilizer.

Up until recently, this program was being used only to write files.
Many (most) of the properties written have getters, but no setters because of the above.

The object's fields are written from deserializing a JSON body of a web request
and the properties written to the xml file are calculated from these.

For example:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "DeliveryNet")]
public decimal DeliveryNet { get { return Math.Round((100M * price_delivery) / (fee.vat_rate + 100M), 2); } set { } }
```

I just need to make these blank setters actually do something, then it should work fine.